# django and DB modeling: I think I've got Many to Many wrong

Tags: django, database, many-to-many, relationship, data-modeling

I have an object `Option` which is like a type, it only has a property: `name` (it could have more properties in the future).
Instances of `Option` have a unique name.

Many objects may have zero or more of `Option` instances.

For example:

```
class Consumer:
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Option, blank=True, help_text="the options")
```

But then, in order to create the `Option` instances for `Consumer`'s many-to-many `options` relationship, I need to create a new `Option` instance and add it to `options`.

This however "breaks" my uniqueness: Now I have two with the same name! And so forth for every instance of `Option` I create.for `Many-to-Many` links. Instead of the 4 I need, I have now 68 in my DB...

I believe I have fundamentally misunderstood `Many-To-Man`y, and / or mis-designed this relationship...

Can anybody help?

EDIT: Here's how I set options in an example:

```
def enable_option(request, pk=0, option_pk=0, *args, **kwargs):
    consumer = get_object_or_404(Consumer, pk=pk)
    option = get_object_or_404(Option, pk=option_pk)

    new_option = Option()
    new_option.name = option.name // I know I am breaking my own rule...but when I read the consumer options, I need the exact same name! Still, I believe I am modeling wrong
    new_option.save()
    consumer.options.add(new_option)
    consumer.save()

    return HttpResponse()
```

Comment: You can add constraint to Option model name field: `name = models.CharField(unique=True)`. This is guarantee that you will not have options with the same name. When you add Option to Customer you can use get_or_create method: `customer.options.add(Option.objects.get_or_create(name=option_name)`. Nothing else I can advise, without seeing how you add options to customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why you create a new Option here. You get the existing one; you can just add that to the relationship:

```
consumer = get_object_or_404(Consumer, pk=pk)
option = get_object_or_404(Option, pk=option_pk)
consumer.options.add(option)
```

You don't even need to call `save`, as modifying an m2m does not change the instance itself.

Comment: you are soooo right! thank youu! I had it actually like this before, BUT, instead of getting the option by id and adding it, I was creating new in_memory objects, thus after adding it wasn't saved! Then, investigating m2m, I found an example sayin you need to save your object first....that got me in trouble :) I also now finally understand how django manages m2m, which is great! Thus, upvoted and accepted